# no module named "app" while trying to install a boilerplate Django

Tags: django, docker-compose

I'm trying to install a boilerplate in my personal computer but I'm getting this error:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/app/manage.py", line 7, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 401, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 377, in execute
    django.setup()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 24, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 91, in populate
    app_config = AppConfig.create(entry)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 90, in create
    module = import_module(entry)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1030, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1007, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 984, in _find_and_load_unlocked
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'app'
```

The boilerplate I'm trying to install is this one:

https://github.com/jayfk/launchr

The error happens specifically when I introduce this command:

```
docker-compose run app python manage.py migrate
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this in your console:

```
git clone https://github.com/jayfk/launchr.git
cd launchr
docker-compose run app python manage.py migrate
```

This worked for me

Comment: yes it worked! Thank you, although now this pops out: ```django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Requested setting DEBUG, but settings are not configured. You must either define the environment variable DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE or call settings.configure() before accessing settings.```

You know why that can be?

Comment: Do you get this error during docker-compose run app python manage.py migrate or when running server?

Comment: when running server

Comment: When I run docker-compose up server started

Comment: wait yes, I was trying to do ```python manage.py runserver``` Thank you now it works!